# Problems understanding tutorial on pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

This code was taken from cplusplus.com. It's used in a tutorial to explain pointers, which I'm struggling to understand.

When they write that p1 = 20; towards the end of the code, wouldn't that change the memory address of the first value as well as the second value? Since they've already made p1 = p2 previously in the code.

If anyone has a different way of explaining it apart from their comments from the website or another tutorial?

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
  int * p1, * p2;

  p1 = &firstvalue;  // p1 = address of firstvalue
  p2 = &secondvalue; // p2 = address of secondvalue
  *p1 = 10;          // value pointed to by p1 = 10
  *p2 = *p1;         // value pointed to by p2 = value pointed to by p1
  p1 = p2;           // p1 = p2 (value of pointer is copied)
  *p1 = 20;          // value pointed to by p1 = 20

  cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << '\n';
  cout << "secondvalue is " << secondvalue << '\n';
}
```

Taken from "http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/"

Comment: You should learn from a C++ book, not random "tuts" on the internet.

Comment: Not seeing any function `front()` nor any `priority_queue`, here.

Comment: Where's the priority queue in your code? Where is the "front" that doesn't work? BTW: When quoting others or their code, you can include a link to their work, too.

Comment: Sorry I was drafting another question earlier today and forgot to change the title!

Comment: Here's a crazy idea for you: change the title such that it matches the question.

Comment: Instead of apologising just fix the title (I've done it for you now).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Diagrams might explain this more easily.

> ```
>   int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
> ```

This means that somewhere in memory, two `int` objects are created:

```
+------------+    +-------------+
|     5      |    |      15     | 
+------------+    +-------------+
```

> ```
>   int * p1, * p2;
>
>   p1 = &firstvalue;  // p1 = address of firstvalue
>   p2 = &secondvalue; // p2 = address of secondvalue
> ```

This means that two pointer objects are created. Their value is such that they point to the two `int` objects:

```
+------------+    +-------------+
|     5      |    |      15     | 
+------------+    +-------------+
       ^                 ^
       |                 |
    +----+            +----+
    | p1 |            | p2 |
    +----+            +----+
```

> ```
> *p1 = 10;          // value pointed to by p1 = 10
> ```

This means that the object pointed to by `p1`, i.e. the first `int` object, is modified:

```
+------------+    +-------------+
|     10     |    |      15     | 
+------------+    +-------------+
       ^                 ^
       |                 |
    +----+            +----+
    | p1 |            | p2 |
    +----+            +----+
```

> ```
> *p2 = *p1;         // value pointed to by p2 = value pointed to by p1
> ```

The `int` object pointed to by `p2` shall be set to the same value as the one pointed to by `p1`:

```
+------------+    +-------------+
|     10     |    |      10     | 
+------------+    +-------------+
       ^                 ^
       |                 |
    +----+            +----+
    | p1 |            | p2 |
    +----+            +----+
```

> ```
> p1 = p2;           // p1 = p2 (value of pointer is copied)
> ```

After this line, nothing points to the first `int` object anymore. `p1` points to same object as `p2`:

```
+------------+      +-------------+
|     10     |  +-> |      10     | 
+------------+  |   +-------------+
                |          ^
                |          |
    +----+      |       +----+
    | p1 |------+       | p2 |
    +----+              +----+
```

> ```
> *p1 = 20;          // value pointed to by p1 = 20
> ```

The object pointed to by `p1` (which happens to be the same one pointed to by `p2`) is set to 20:

```
+------------+      +-------------+
|     10     |  +-> |      20     | 
+------------+  |   +-------------+
                |          ^
                |          |
    +----+      |       +----+
    | p1 |------+       | p2 |
    +----+              +----+
```

Here we go. The first `int` is 10, the second is 20.

Comment: That diagram was very helpful and this was clearly explained, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> When they write that p1 = 20; towards the end of the code, wouldn't that change the memory address of the first value as well as the second value? Since they've already made p1 = p2 previously in the code.

They wrote `*p1 = 20` actually, but that's why you're right, yes.

If you're confused because the program still emits two different values, well that's because you're printing `firstvalue` and `secondvalue` (which are still different), not `*p1` and `*p2` (which are both `secondvalue` by that point).

You didn't explain why this confuses you or what your question is, or what on earth this has to do with `priority_queue`s, so this is all I can tell you.

Comment: I don't understand why they don't just end up pointing to the same value and printing the same value.

Comment: @17DOWN: [They would, if you actually printed them](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67cacf312421ee42). But you're not printing through the pointers, in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I have given comments for your understanding

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int firstvalue = 5, secondvalue = 15;
  int * p1, * p2;

  p1 = &firstvalue;  // *p1 = 5, since p1 is pointing to firstvalue
  p2 = &secondvalue; // *p2 = 15, since p2 is pointing to secondvalue
  *p1 = 10;          // *p1=10, changing firstvalue to 10
  *p2 = *p1;         // now *p2=10;
  p1 = p2;           // p1 is now pointing to secondvalue whose value is already changed into 10 by *p2=*p1; statement.
  *p1 = 20;          // now secondvalue=20 since p1 is pointing to second value

  cout << "firstvalue is " << firstvalue << '\n'; //prints 10
  cout << "secondvalue is " << secondvalue << '\n'; //prints 20
}
```

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit can I get my +ve back, if you think it is corrected.